# how to load image from internel memory when glide fails to load

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

i want to know that how to load image from uri when glide fails to load image from URL.

i have tried using the error function on glide but it requires drawable resource.

```
Glide.with(this@Main2Activity).load("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGTVf63Vm3XgOncMVSOy0-jSxdMT8KVJIc8WiWaevuWiPGe0Pm").error(Glide.with(this).load(image)).into(images)
```

it is giving error that it requires drawable resource to work on

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time before,

what i did was that i used [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) which does the same thing as Glide but provides a `placeHolder` method which can place an image for your imageview and if it fails loading from the url it will just keep the placeholder image.

You can refer to the tutorial linked [here](https://square.github.io/picasso/)